# Сертификация Microsoft. Есть ли смысл?

Tags: .net, сертификат

В поисках первой работы на junior .NET разработчика появилась идея получить сертификацию.
Подскажите, есть ли в этом практический смысл? Увеличит ли это шансы? Как я указал - работа первая, т.е. опыта коммерческой разработки нет.

Конкретно, я думал получить [MCSD: Web Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcsd-web-apps-certification.aspx).
Для этого необходимо сдать 3 экзамена:

1. Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3 (бесплатно)
2. Developing ASP.NET 4.5 MVC Web Applications (80$)
3. Developing Windows Azure and Web Services (80$)

В принципе подготовиться - не проблема, но не уверен есть ли в них смысл и стоит ли тратить 160$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Практического смысла нет.
Опыт важнее, в последствии когда будет опыт наличие сертификации даст преимущества при прочих равных.

Пока опыта нет , сертификация не есть ключевым моментом.
Наберешся опыта и сам потом решишь нужна ли тебе сертификация.

Comment: Да в принципе сама сертификация конкретно мне нафиг не нужна, я только надеялся, что это может увеличить шансы на поиск первой работы и кандидат (т.е. я) будет выглядеть как-то интереснее и серьезнее на фоне других таких же людей без опыта но и без сертификаций. Конечно понятно, что главное это техническое собеседование, но я подумал, что с сертификацией как минимум приглашение на собеседование будет почти обеспечено. Или нет?

Comment: У нс (СНГ всмысле) половина людей не верит бумажкам потому что понимает что любую бумажку можно купить.
А вторая половина считает вообще бумажки не нужными.

Comment: Данную сертификацию люди получают по банальным брейндампам в 90% случаях (разве что для себя человек решил систематизировать знания). В итоге - это реально просто бумажка!

Answer (score 5):

Смысл есть в двух случаях:

1) Бумажки помогут вам выделиться при всех прочих равных (в т.ч. если вы новичок).

2) Бумажки помогут вам, если вы будете устраиваться на работу на Западе — там это дело любят.

Во всех остальных случаях опыт ценится куда больше, чем бумажки.